# Is the PCI-E x1 slot of this motherboard faulty?

Tags: pci-express, motherboard

As you may know, GPU risers are composed of two PCBs, one to be connected to a PCI-E slot on motherboard, and the other one has a PCI-E x16 slot for the graphics card. When I insert  the former PCB in a PCI-E x1 slot on this 10+ years old motherboard, there is some short circuit, and consequently, two traces on the PCB are burned. Then if I insert that damaged PCB in a PCI-E x16 slot on the motherboard, the graphics card works properly, with no problem that I can observe. This has happened with two different GPU risers, so I guess riser isn't the cultprit. By the way, the motherboard has only one PCI-E x1 slot.

How can I test if the motherboard or the graphics card is faulty without damaging other PCBs? And why does the damaged PCB work on a PCI-E x16 slot?

Comment: A PCI-E x16 slot can provide 75W and a x16 card can draw 75W if no external power connectors are used. The x1 slot can provide 10W, which is not enough to power a x16 card, unless there is some way of feeding external power on the adapter to the x16 slot. Is there?

Comment: @Justme, Yes, the second PCB described above is powered by a 6 pin PCI-E connector.